# Overlaying n (user generated) points over a graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, points

```
print "Enter the amount of points you would like to generate to estimate Pi"
n = raw_input()

plt.xlim((0,1))
plt.ylim((0,1))

x = numpy.linspace(0,1,500)
y = numpy.sqrt(1-x**2)

for i in range(int(n)):
    xcoordinate = random.random()
    ycoordinate = random.random()

plt.scatter(xcoordinate, ycoordinate)
plt.plot(x,y,'g')
plt.show()
```

I'm trying to get `n` random points scattered across this graph. Instead I only get a single random point.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn `xcoordinate` and `xcoordinate` into a list instead, and append random points in it.

```
xcoordinate=[]
ycoordinate=[]
for i in range(int(n)):
    xcoordinate.append(random.random())
    ycoordinate.append(random.random())
```

The rest of your code remains unchanged.

[image]

Comment: This works well actually because I plan to average points under the curve with points over the curve. Is there a way to say something like if (point is under or equal to curve), put +1 value in list a. If point is above curve, put +1 value in list b. After that is done, I'd like to average the value of the two lists. Can this be done?

Comment: @seeaemearohin Yes it can be done. To check if the point is below the circle line, you can calculate the [distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) of a point from point (0,0). As for the rest.. you should try them out on your own, and if you get a specific problem, ask for help.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your help! Instead of using distance, is it possible to use an algorithm like this?

under = []
above = []

if xcoordinate and ycoordinate <= y:
    under.append(1)
    print "Of" + n + " points," + len(under) + " are under the curve"
    
else:
    above.append(1)
    print " and" + len(above) + " are above the curve."

Comment: @seeaemearohin No, you *must* use distance and check if it is smaller or equal to the circle radius. You could use `if (x**2 + y**2)**(0.5) <= radius:`

Comment: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all(). It thinks I'm trying to pass a boolean operation through the if.